# python webdriver's is_element_present does not work when object not exist

Tags: python, webdriver

after record with selenium ide,i got this method in my code:

```
def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        return False
    return True
```

when object exist it works fine:

```
print self.is_element_present("id","kw")
```

i got true

but when object not exist :

```
print self.is_element_present("id","kw1")
```

in a long time (more than self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)),i got nothing

Comment: it looks like there is something wrong with my os or my Firefox browser, this method works fine in Ie and Chrome under win7 an Firefox under ubuntu.  but it still doesn't work with my Firefox under win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of webdriver and firefox compatibility is the first thing to check.  FF16 works well with 2.25 for java.  I think 2.26 supports 17 as well.  What versions do you have of each?

Edit : For python change log doesnt talk beyond FF13 :  http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/py/CHANGES